# How to add double header to a handsontable?

Tags: jquery, handsontable

i use jquery-handsontable plugin. and i need to implement some kind of table:
[image: handsontable with double header and colspan]

How to add double header, and besides 1st part of the header must be with colspan ? Is it possible? If yes, then how can i achieve such result?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Alright, it might be a little late to answer but if it helps.
You have to use the parameter 'nestedHeaders' as follow

```
nestedHeaders:[
            [{label: ''}, {label: 'January', colspan: 3}, {label: 'February', colspan:3}],
            ['', 'blah', 'blahblahblah', 'blah', 'bonus', 'blahblahblah', 'bonus']],
```